# NumPy unique() returning array instead of scalar

Tags: arrays, numpy, unique

I have a 3465 x 50157 NumPy matrix and am trying to test a certain computation using each unique value in a chosen column of the matrix as a threshold value. Consider the following example:

```
feat_num = 4
thresholds = np.unique(X[:, feat_num])

for thresh in thresholds:
    y_left = np.array([
        y[i] for i in range(X.shape[0]) if X[i, feat_num] < thresh
    ])
```

When running this, numpy is giving me the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().
```

I have confirmed that `X[i, feat_num]` is a scalar, so there is no issue there. However, for some reason, `thresh` is evaluating to an array of some sort. I don't see how this could be, given that `X` is just a large matrix of integers.

Anyone see what is going on?

Comment: what is y ? or what is X only one array shape is described in your question

Comment: And `thresh` is also a scalar?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you're using a numpy `matrix` rather than a numpy `ndarray`. The latter are more general beasts, and I would suggest that you use those. One of the advantages of the `matrix` type is that algebraic operations work as you'd expect it from matrices, but this is rarely what one needs, and even in those cases `numpy.dot` can be used to make it work with `ndarray` objects.

So, the problem is that a column slice of your `matrix` is a column vector, i.e. a `matrix` of shape `(N,1)` (which is equivalent to a list of lists). If your original array was an `ndarray`, then the column slice would have shape `(N,)`, i.e. it would be a 1d `ndarray` (compatible with flat lists) rather than an actual column vector:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X = np.random.rand(3,3)
>>> Xmat = np.asmatrix(X)
>>> 
>>> print(X[:,1])
[ 0.28797057  0.56186287  0.58674852]
>>> print(Xmat[:,1])
[[ 0.28797057]
 [ 0.56186287]
 [ 0.58674852]]
```

Looping over the column vector will give you lists rather than scalars, contrary to your expectations.

If you don't make use of matrix operations anywhere, then I strongly suggest switching to `np.array` objects, which should also solve your current problem.